# Ingress is not up for GKE getting error: Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: received errors when updating backend service

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy a backend through helm. It seems the ingress is saying in creation forever and after the sync it is giving the error: Error syncing to GCP: error running backend syncing routine: received errors when updating backend service: googleapi: Error 400: INSTANCE_IN_MULTIPLE_LOAD_BALANCED_IGS - Validation failed for instance 'projects/sxxxxxxx/instances/gke-gke1-default-1-cb3c8ee2-0bap': instance may belong to at most one load-balanced instance group. googleapi

Here is the template for Ingress and Service

```
# Source: analytics/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    app: dx-analytics-eu-backend
  name: dx-analytics-ingress-eu-backend
  namespace: xxxxxx
spec: 
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/%s/v1/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: dx-analytics-eu-backend
                port:
                  number: 8088

# Source: analytics/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dx-analytics-eu-backend
  namespace: xxxxx
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"https":"HTTPS","http":"HTTP"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"exposed_ports": {"8088":{}}}'
  labels:
    app: dx-analytics-eu-backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8088
      targetPort: 8088
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: dx-analytics-eu-backend


# Source: analytics/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dx-analytics-deployment-eu-backend
  namespace: xxxxxx
  labels:
    app: dx-analytics-eu-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dx-analytics-eu-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dx-analytics-eu-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dx-analytics
        image: "xxxxxxxx"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent     
        ports:
        - name: "http"
          containerPort: 8088
          protocol: TCP
```

cleaned up the whole env, by uninstalling old charts. Also no hanging back end.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you are receiving may indicate that the instance `gke-gke1-default-1-cb3c8ee2-0bap` is part of one or more instance groups. These instance groups may also be a part of a backend service which is not in use by any load balancer. Please verify if this is the case.

> *Validation failed for instance 'projects/sxxxxxxx/instances/gke-gke1-default-1-cb3c8ee2-0bap': instance may belong to at most one load-balanced instance group. googleapi*

Ingress controller manages a separate unmanaged instance group to build L7 Load Balancer. However, GCE requires instances to only belong to 1 instance group used by LBs. Please see the [Restrictions and guidance for instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#restrictions_and_guidance)

Assuming that the instance is indeed part of one or more instance group used in a backend service that are not part of any LB, then you may delete the said backend service and remove the backend vm (`gke-gke1-default-1-cb3c8ee2-0bap`) from these instance groups so that the ingress will create a new instance group with the above mentioned vm.